# Border around screen C#

Tags: c#, wpf, border

I'm developing an application and I want to display a colored border (not into a window) around the screen (Skype-like). I've searched all the day on the Internet but I didn't find anything.

**EDIT**
I've already tried this:

```
<Border BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Red">
```

into my XAML and it displays the border around the window, but I want it around the whole screen even if I minimize the window.

**EDIT:**
I don't want to have a border for my app but a red border around all the screen, i think there must exist a windows API that allows it.

Comment: what you  have tried  so  far ??

Comment: You cannot draw a `Border` in a WPF Application that extends outside of that Application.

Comment: I solved creating a new transparent window with red border.

Answer (score 1):

you can do  something like this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Blue" >
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

this  will give u

[image]

Comment: I've tried this (look at the edit in the question), but if I want it even when my window is minimized?

Answer (score 1):

When your window is minimized, it's minimal in size by definition. What you want is actually a maximized window when it is known as minimized by the OS?!

- go to a big window size (equal the maximized state) when you handle the minimized event.
- thin out your app window that only the border is visible, leaving the inner space for the desktop. To give you an idea what the idea is: [click here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88626/Shaped-WPF-Form) (just an example to give the unusual shape) In your case, it would be a thin line - rectangulare shape.

Comment: thank you for response, I edited the question, hope it seems to be clear.

Comment: when you share desktop with Skype it shows a red border all around the screen, i never found a Skype employee that came in my house and put with scissors, paper and adhesive coloured borders around my LCD monitor. thank you for help. :)

Comment: Since Skype belongs to Microsoft they could afford employee visits! I'm somehow oldschool and not familiar with Skype. But the border surely belongs to the Skype app, like a toolwindow.

Answer (score 0):

us this, but change the color and thickness if you wish. If this wasn't what you were asking please develop your question further and give examples.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
```